# Azure Blob Container Alert if specific container folder is not updated in 24hrs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service, azure-alerts

I am wanting to find a way to send an alert if a specific folder in a blob container is not updated within 24 hours. I have tried setting up an alert through the portal, but I can only seem to find Metric alerts based on Ingress of the entire blob container. Is there a way to specify Ingress on a folder within the container?

I am wanting to do this through the Alerts tab in the portal, but if I have to resort to writing code I can go that route also.

Here is a picture of what I have tried so far:
[image: Blob Container Ingress Alert]

Comment: Hi, has your issue been solved ?

Comment: Marked yours as the answer, and we will most likely go with something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no out-of-box solution to monitor a folder in Azure storage container in Azure alert.

Based on your requirement, you want to send an alert if there is no modification in a folder over 24 hours. So we can just get the latest modification time in this folder and compare to the current time. You can try this powershell below :

```
$storageAccount = "<your storage account>"
$resourceGroup = "<your resource group name>"
$containerName = "<container name>"
$folderName = "<folder name>"
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -name $storageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

$lastModifyTimeInFolder = (Get-AzStorageBlob -Prefix $folderName -Container $containerName -Context $storage.Context | Sort-Object -Property LastModified -Descending)[0].LastModified
$now = Get-Date


if($lastModifyTimeInFolder.CompareTo($now.AddHours(-24)) -ge 0){
echo "modified within 24hs"
}else {
#if last $lastModifyTimeInFolder less than current time minus 24 hours, you can trigger your own alert based on your logic here 
echo "modified exceeded 24hs "
}
```

You can create a [runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook) in Azure automation as [a scheduled task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules#creating-a-schedule) i,e run this script each 30 mins to implement your requirement.

Hope it helps.